# How to time a specific function of code block in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, time, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm and playing with the profiler it has built in. I've keyed in on some areas where my code can be optimized but I was wondering if there was a way to step through the code and see how long each line took to execute as I stepped through without having to rerun all my code in the profiler.

Comment: a stopwatch ... i guess

Answer (score 0):

I think the closes you could do is put a breakpoint

then open up the debugger and enter console mode

and execute the statement as `started=time.time();my_function();print("Took %0.2fs"%(time.time()-started))`